# Prove the following (NBHM analysis 2011 qn 2.1)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive terms.If $\sum n^2a_n^2<\infty$ then $\sum a_n $convergent.

Comment: this has been discusses here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640326/conditions-on-a-n-that-imply-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-a-n please have a look at that!

Comment: Equivalent to [Convergent series exercise from Little Rudin](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/163441)

Answer (score 1):

The estimate you give says that $$\|N A_N \|_2 < C.$$ Where $N A_N$ is the sequence $a_1, 2 a_2, \dotsc, N a_N.$ By Cauchy Schwarts, $$\|N A_N\| \| 1/N\| \geq \|A_N\|.$$ (here $\|1/N\|$ is the $L^2$ norm of the vector $1, 1/2, \dotsc, 1/N$). Since $\|1/N\| \leq \infty,$ you are done.