# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges then $(n^2 a_n)$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is a proof of a statement similar to the contrapositive of my statement [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640326/conditions-on-a-n-that-imply-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-nbh) (first case) but I suppose there is an error in the proof as $a_n>L\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ does not imply that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n\neq L$ (consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$). First of all, is this statement even true if $(a_n)$ is NOT positive for all $n$? If so, how can it be proven?

The following is my attempt at a proof (arranged from the linked question):

*Proof*. Suppose that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n^2 a_n=L$ for some $L\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |n^2 a_n|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n^2|a_n|=|L|$. So we have that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |a_n|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} n^2|a_n|=0\cdot |L|=0$.

(Here goes the missing part showing that $|a_n|<\frac{|L|}{n^2}$ ultimately)

Then since $|a_n|<\frac{|L|}{n^2}$ ultimately, we have the following

$$
0\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|L|}{n^2}
$$
Note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|L|}{n^2}$ converges by the p-test so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges by the squeeze theorem. Thus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely by the absolute convergence theorem.

Comment: Simpler: If $(n^2 a_n)$ is *bounded* then $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: The error in the linked post was easily corrected in the two answers.

Comment: @MartinR Oh my. So if $(n^2 a_n)$ has a limit then it is bounded, hence $\exists M>0 \quad n^2 a_n \leq M$ so $a_n\leq \frac{M}{n^2}$ and the rest follows similar to above right?

Comment: Yes, a convergent sequence is bounded: $|n^2 a_n | \le M$ etc. It does not matter if all $a_n$ are positive or not.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry to bother you about this, given that this turned out to be a very silly question, should I just delete it or write out an answer to it?

Comment: Also, if  $0\leqslant (n^2 a_n)$ converges, then $ (a_n)$ converges too.

Comment: That is up to you. You'll have to decide if this is a question (and answer) that future readers might read and benefit/learn from.

Comment: @zkutch Why do we need $0\leq(n^2 a_n)$ to have that $(a_n)$ converges here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct proof for people like me who couldn't figure it out from replies to the linked post.

Proof by contrapositive. If $(n^2 a_n)$ is convergent, then it is bounded. That is
$$\exists M>0 \text{ s.t. } |n^2a_n|\leq M\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
But then
$$0\leq|a_n|\leq \frac{M}{n^2}\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N} \text{ since } n^2>0$$
Note that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{M}{n^2}$ converges by the p-series test. So $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges by the comparison test. Thus $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely by the absolute convergence theorem.